# How to change the order to choose os during boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have recently installed Ubuntu in my laptop alongside Windows 10 by dual booting. And at the start grub is showing up to give options between Ubuntu os and Windows boot loader.

If I don't do anything for some time, Ubuntu gets selected automatically. Instead of Ubuntu I want Windows to get selected if I don't do anything. How can I do that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To change the default loading entry, you need to change the `GRUB_DEFAULT` as given below.

you need to edit `/etc/default/grub` . To do that,

Execute :  `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Now change the `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to any entry you wish.

The first entry is `0` , second Entry is `1` and so on..

[image]

After editing, update your grub by executing : `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Doesn't work for dual boot with Ubuntu (16.04) and Ubuntu (17.04).

Answer (score 7):

If you would like to have a graphical interface, you may want to use Grub Customizer:
As [Tico](https://askubuntu.com/users/199716/tico) pointed out, install it by adding the ppa first:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

This tool lets you modify grub rather safely. It allows you to re-order grub's menu entries, set the default entry, and remove an entry, etc.

Comment: I believe you'll nedd the PPA for it: https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer