# Is there a grub- reboot equivalent to do a one-time boot into ubuntu from windows?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, easybcd

bcdedit doesnt list ubuntu as boot entry in Win7.Can the grub boot order be modified from windows?
What if I set win7 as default OS with timeout set as 0 in grub from ubuntu and reboot? Would I be stuck in Windows forever?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that changing Grub bootloader is possible via Windows. However you can set the grub to default to Windows as a default choice, instead of Ubuntu.

I will not recommend timeout set to 0 (unless you have some serious ninja skills). Its best to keep a short duration like 5 seconds if you do not wish to stay too long at the grub menu, or suppose if you wish to open Ubuntu sometimes.

Here is how to change the boot order in Grub:

To change the default loading entry, you need to change the GRUB_DEFAULT as given below.

you need to `edit /etc/default/grub` . To do that,

Execute : `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Now change the `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to any entry you wish.

The first entry is 0 , second Entry is 1 and so on..

[image]

Source: [How to change the order to choose os during boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781157/how-to-change-the-order-to-choose-os-during-boot)