# How do I change the boot loader of dualboot windows 10 and Ubuntu18.04LTS?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I wish to change the boot loader to grub instead of Windows.

I tried the solution:

1. [How to change the order to choose os during boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781157/how-to-change-the-order-to-choose-os-during-boot/781159)

but was not solved.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

GRUB 2 builds its menu by running scripts found in the /etc/grub.d/ folder and the settings in the /etc/default/grub file.

What I usually do is rename the os-prober script file to take precedence, before script 10_linux.

```
sudo mv /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober /etc/grub.d/06_os-prober
```

Don't forget to `sudo update-grub2` after.